# c#, refactor property to access private field to expression - bodied property

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper

Given something like this

```
public bool Hidden
{
    get => _hidden;
    private set => _hidden = value;
}
```

Or

```
public bool Hidden { get; private set; }
```

I would like to refactor the above so all set accessors of the Hidden property uses the _hidden field. In other words the property should look like this afterwards:

```
public bool Hidden => _hidden;
```

and all accessors in the class should assign a value to the field _hidden.

But I dont know how to do this using Resharper?

Answer (score 0):

There is no chance to do this ootb with ReSharper, that's too complex. You'd have to write a custom plugin for that.

JetBrains has [this](https://github.com/jetbrains/resharper-rider-plugin) fantastic template which gets you started quite fast.